# How to combine this two "FOR" loops into one?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to combine two FOR loops into one.

Here is my code :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set BackupDest=D:\backup

for /D %%I in ("%HomeDrive%\users\*") do if exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\" (

xcopy "%HomeDrive%\users\%%~nI\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\Desktop\" /e /i /y
xcopy "%HomeDrive%\users\%%~nI\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\Documents\" /e /i /y

)

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%HomeDrive%\users\*" ^| findstr /b /e /i /l /v /g:"%~dp0\bin\exclude_users.txt"') do if not exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\" (
echo Destination folder of the user %%~nI is missing
)
```

I'm note sure if we can do that in this case ?

If yes, how I can achieve this ?

Any help is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "BackupDest=D:\backup"

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (
    'dir /a:d-h /b "%HomeDrive%\users\*" ^| findstr /b /e /i /l /v /g:"%~dp0exclude_user.txt"'
) do (
    if exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nxI\" (
        xcopy "%HomeDrive%\users\%%~nxI\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%~nxI\Desktop\" /e /i /y
        xcopy "%HomeDrive%\users\%%~nxI\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%~nxI\Documents\" /e /i /y
    ) else (
        echo Destination folder of the user %%~nxI is missing
    )
)
```

Use `if exist ... (...) else (...)` syntax.

A name of a folder uses the modifiers `nx`, as a folder can be named i.e. `firstname.lastname`.
If you only use `n`, then you would only get a part of the folder name `firstname`.

Comment: The code works for typical user profile folders, but fails if a user profile folder starts with a space and/or a semicolon. This is of course very unlikely. `"tokens=*"` results in first removing all leading spaces/tabs from line (folder name without path) and next checking if the remaining string starts with a semicolon in which case the line (folder name) would be ignored by `for`. Better is the usage of `"eol=| delims="` which disables line splitting behavior completely and makes sure no folder name is ignored as no folder name can have `|` in its name.

Comment: It would be also better to use just `%%I` in this case instead of `%%~nxI`. `dir` outputs the folder names found in `%HomeDrive%\users` without path exactly as existing in that folder. The usage of `%%~nxI` results in searching in current directory for a file or directory with name as assigned to loop variable `I` and if such a file/folder really exists in current directory, the name and extension in current directory is used instead of the folder name in users directory.

Comment: For example, if `C:\Users` contains a directory `UserName` and current directory has a file or directory `USERNAME`, `%%~nxI` expands to `USERNAME` while `%%I` would expand to `UserName`. So it would be better to use in this code `%%I` to avoid an additional file system access in current directory for each directory name assigned to loop variable `I` during the loop iterations and perhaps changing the case of the letters of directory name.